# Get dynamic data from firebase and push local web page

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, webview

Is this possible get firebase data and pushing in a html page which is located in assets folder ? But the data has dynamically changing.

So someting like code bellow.

```
String js = "javascript:var x =document.getElementById('username').value = 'firebasedata';
```

And how can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach a listener to the location, and code inside will do the work for you

```
var starCountRef = firebase.database().ref('userData');
starCountRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  updateUsername(postElement, snapshot.val());
});
```

Read more here 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write